# "Task not serializable" error in Spark code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm getting `Task not serializable` error from the following code.

```
   var inputRDD = sc.textFile(inputPath).flatMap(line => line.split(":")).map{word => (word)} 
   var i = 1
   var characters:Array[String] = new Array[String](3)
   characters = Array("a","i","m")    
   for (i <- 1 to 4){
     inputRDD.foreach { word =>
          sc.broadcast(replacement)
          val result = word.replaceAll(replacement, "b")
          println(word,result)
          replacement = characters(i)        
      }
     }
```

I couldn't find any help online. I need some help here.
Thanks

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do here.

Comment: It's wonderfully mysterious! I have no idea either. The `map` in the first line does nothing. The `i` on the second line is unused. The initial value of `characters` is not used and immediately replaced. Why not start with the final value? Then all `var`s could be `val`s. Inside the `foreach` you try to create a broadcast variable for `replacement` which is undeclared. The broadcast variable is immediately discarded. You try to index a 3-element array from 1 to 4. The only line that makes sense is the `println`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@maasg has already answered your question. But the code is so wrong, I think you need some help to get it working. I don't know if you've read through http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html.

Your mistakes:

- `map{word => (word)}` in the first line does nothing. It just maps each word to itself.
- The `i` on the second line is unused. The `for` loop declares a new variable. You don't need to pre-declare the loop variable.
- The initial value of `characters` is not used and immediately replaced. Why not start with the final value? Then all `var`s could be `val`s. `val`s are easier to work with because they don't change values.
- Inside the `foreach` you try to create a broadcast variable for `replacement` which is undeclared. The `sc.broadcast` has to be called in code that runs on the driver (the body of `foreach` will run in the executors). `sc.broadcast` returns a broadcast variable, which you can then use inside the code that runs on the executors. Instead, you just from the returned variable on the ground.
- `broadcast` is only important for large values (like >10kB). Don't worry about it for now.
- You try to index a 3-element array (`characters`) from 1 to 4. The valid indexes are from 0 to 2.
- `foreach` cannot be used to modify an RDD. RDDs are immutable. You need to use `map` instead to create a new, modified RDD from the original RDD.

My guess for what you're trying to do is to load a file, split on colons and replace three letters (`a`, `i`, `m`) with `b`. Here's how to do it:

```
def replaceLetters(filename: String,
                   patterns: Seq[String],
                   replacement: String): RDD[String] = {
  val words = sc.textFile(filename).flatMap(_.split(":"))
  words.map { word =>
    patterns.foldLeft(word) {
      (word, pattern) => word.replaceAll(pattern, replacement)
    }
  }
}

// Call our function, print the results.
replaceLetters("my_file", "a,i,m".split(","), "b").collect.foreach(println(_))
```

Answer (score 1):

This code tries to use the SparkContext (`sc`) within a closure on an RDD. The `sparkContext` is not serializable and is not meant to be serialized in its usage.

It's unclear to me what this code is trying to achieve, but it will need to be changed to remove the use of `sparkContext` from any closure.